# Parallel execution is not stopping in JUnit 5 runner for Karate feature files

Tags: api, karate, cucumber-junit, parallel-execution

**Karate(version -0.9.4)** - There is one single feature file in which there are 4 Scenario Outline is used and If I run this feature file individually then it is working fine. But when the same file is added in a Parallel run, then the parallel execution is not stopping. The below error is showing
[Error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKlhF.png)

Due to this issue, the cucumber report is not getting generated.

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade to 1.0.1 and confirm.

Comment: Hi Peter, I upgrade to version 1.0.1 but no success. But later on, I found the issue. The issue with the JSON test data input in one scenario. But I don't understand how that API was working fine when I ran the single feature file. Thanks

Comment: @Dream_hat we consider it a serious bug if parallel execution hangs. so if you can follow this process so that we can REPLICATE this - please do so, else please carry on like before: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue